# How to close streamwriter correctly after if statement is no more true?

Tags: c#, streamwriter, unity-game-engine

I am using streamwriter to save my data of the game while playing in a csv-file. In order to do this, I initialized my streamwriter in the startfunction and wrote a first line for the headers for my data. Then in the update function I write the changing game variables in that file. The problem I have is the following:

This works fine and I can see my csv file with the data when I click stop manually within the game. However, when I wait until myTimer (the duration of the game is <=0) and the GUI is reloading I just get an empty csv file. 
I think the problem is related to the fact that I do not close my streamwriter correctly... Here is my code:

```
// Use this for initialization
public void Start () 
{
    //create file (txt or csv) with streamwriter which has the name of the Subject and Information which game
    swFeedbackGame = File.CreateText (UIManagerScript.SUBJECTID+"FeedbackGameData444.csv"); 
    //write headers to file 
    swFeedbackGame.Write ("PositionRingFeeback" + "," + "PositionSphereMiddle" + "," + "distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere" + "," + "Collisions" + "," + "Timer"+System.Environment.NewLine); 
}

public void SaveDataFeedback() 
{
    //start writing in file only when feedback game is starting 
    //if (StartButtonManager.startingGame) {

    if (StartButtonManager.startingGame) 
    {
        //get position of center of the ring
        PositionRingFeedback = GameObject.Find ("Ring").transform.position; 

        //position of the center of the ring (y axis) 
        PositionRINGFeedback = PositionRingFeedback.y; 

        //error, meaning difference between position of the spheremiddle and center of the ring 
        distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere = PositionRINGFeedback - Sinewave.posSpheremiddle; 

        //write data to file _ columns are separated by a , 
        swFeedbackGame.Write (PositionRINGFeedback + "," + Sinewave.posSpheremiddle + "," + distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere + "," + CounterManager.counterHitSinewave + "," + UIManagerScript.myTimer + System.Environment.NewLine); 
        swFeedbackGame.Flush (); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        swFeedbackGame.Close (); 
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void FixedUpdate () 
{
    //saves the data from the FeedbackGame every Frame 
    SaveDataFeedback (); 
}
```

Comment: could you please properly indent the code

Comment: seems everytime you reloading the csv file is recreate, check before write if exist then text will appeand and if not exist then create new file

Comment: How about initialization inside a `using(){}` block and then inject the stream writer into `SaveDataFeedback()` rather than relying on a global instance?

Comment: @Mathias: Thank you for your suggestion. Would I have to use the using() in the StartFunction or how? Could you make an example? Because my headers should be written only once in that file whereas all the other variables should be written every frame in it.

Comment: @sportente you shouldn't use `using` because it has a local scope. If you are working with `StreamWriter` in two different methods (for example open and close) you should do it manually. The problem is that you overwrite it each time you run your application. Just use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. Thus use `StreamWriter` constructor manually, which has an option to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your stream inside a using like so:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter)
{
  //your code here this
  //this doesn't need a sw.Open(), or sw.Close()
}
```

but be careful if you have a nested streams.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid opening/closing files or keeping long gaps between open and close in different methods. Keep both the operations in same method.

The `WriteAllText` and `AppendAllText` static methods come in handy. They open the file, write the contents into it, and then close the file in just one statement.

Unless there will be too many calls to write contents to file, I would prefer using these methods, rather than explicitly opening and closing them myself.

```
// Use this for initialization
string FileName;
public void Start()
{
    FileName = UIManagerScript.SUBJECTID + "FeedbackGameData444.csv";

    //create file (txt or csv) with streamwriter which has the name of the Subject and Information which game
    //and write headers to file 
    WriteToFile(FileName, true, "PositionRingFeeback" + "," + "PositionSphereMiddle" + "," + "distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere" + "," + "Collisions" + "," + "Timer" + System.Environment.NewLine);
}

public void SaveDataFeedback()
{
    //start writing in file only when feedback game is starting 
    //if (StartButtonManager.startingGame) {

    if (StartButtonManager.startingGame)
    {
        //get position of center of the ring
        PositionRingFeedback = GameObject.Find("Ring").transform.position;

        //position of the center of the ring (y axis) 
        PositionRINGFeedback = PositionRingFeedback.y;

        //error, meaning difference between position of the spheremiddle and center of the ring 
        distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere = PositionRINGFeedback - Sinewave.posSpheremiddle;

        //write data to file _ columns are separated by a , 
        WriteToFile(FileName, false, PositionRINGFeedback + "," + Sinewave.posSpheremiddle + "," + distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere + "," + CounterManager.counterHitSinewave + "," + UIManagerScript.myTimer + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    //saves the data from the FeedbackGame every Frame 
    SaveDataFeedback();
}

private void WriteToFile(string fileName, bool createNew, string contents)
{
    if (createNew)
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, contents);
    else
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, contents);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can not vote your answer...=( it is not possible. The problem is when I write: WriteToFile, it appears red... do i need a special toolbox for that? When I go on it it is written this is not existing in this context. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added that method at the end of code. Did you miss that?

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will try that. Where can I choose where a new file will be created? I am working on MAC.

Comment: The `createNew` parameter determines whether new file will be created, or existing file updated. Just pass it `True` or `False` appropriately.

Comment: It seems bad to create multiple file handlers for writing one single line of text...

Answer (score 0):

OOP comes to the resque.

Of course, it's verbouse a bit, but it's a good design which you always can extend and so on. Logic about logging is incapculated, so caller can dispose your logger itself and you just have to write whatever you want (note that you pass your game object data, and logger do everything for you). Sample code:

```
class Game
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Game(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _logger.StartWriting();
    }

    public void SaveDataFeedback()
    {
        var dataobject = new GameData();
        // filling data object
        _logger.WriteData(dataobject);
    }
}

internal interface ILogger
{
    void StartWriting();
    void WriteData(GameData data);
}

public class GameData
{
    public double PositionRingFeeback { get; set; }
    public double PositionSphereMiddle { get; set; }
    public double DistanceRingFeedbackToSphere { get; set; }
    public int Collisions { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Timer { get; set; }
}

class FileLogger : ILogger, IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _filename;
    private StreamWriter _sr;

    public FileLogger(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    public void StartWriting()
    {
        _sr = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(_filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.UTF8);
        _sr.WriteLine("PositionRingFeeback" + "," + "PositionSphereMiddle" + "," + "distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere" + "," + "Collisions" + "," + "Timer");
    }

    public void WriteData(GameData data)
    {
        _sr.Write("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", data.PositionRingFeeback, data.PositionSphereMiddle, data.DistanceRingFeedbackToSphere, data.Collisions, data.Timer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then callee is disposing a logger itself:

```
using (var logger = new FileLogger("data.txt"))
{
    var game = new Game(logger);
    game.Start();
}
```

---

If you do not need such level of incapsulation, you can use just events:

```
class Game
{
    public delegate void GameStartedHandler(Game sender, EventArgs eventArgs);
    public delegate void GameEventHandler(Game sender, GameData eventData);

    public event GameStartedHandler GameStarted = delegate { };
    public event GameEventHandler GameEvent = delegate { };

    public void Start()
    {
        GameStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SaveDataFeedback()
    {
        var dataobject = new GameData();
        // filling data object
        GameEvent(this, dataobject);
    }
}
```

but in this case callee is more complex because it should manage all logging itself:

```
using (var logger = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var game = new Game();
    game.GameStarted += (sender, eventArgs) => logger.WriteLine("PositionRingFeeback" + "," + "PositionSphereMiddle" + "," + "distanceRingFeedbackTOSphere" + "," + "Collisions" + "," + "Timer");
    game.GameEvent += (sender, data) => logger.Write("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", data.PositionRingFeeback, data.PositionSphereMiddle, data.DistanceRingFeedbackToSphere, data.Collisions, data.Timer);
    game.Start();
}
```